# MySQL Table Data Import Wizard won't import all rows of an excel file

Tags: mysql

I'm at my wits end.  I've been trying to import a csv file into MySQL for two days and it just won't import the entire thing.  It keeps on stopping at a certain row and I can never figure out why.  It was stopping at row 1497 every time so I went through and deleted all of the commas in the excel file.  Now it stops at row 1506 every time.  I've tried different data formats and switching all of the cell data to "text" and nothing.  It still stops at the same row with no error message so I have no idea why.  I've been into all the threads I could find about this topic and none of the suggestions worked.

Comment: What ui are you using(mysqlworkbench,phpmyadmin, something else) , add table definition and sample rows around 1497 as text , try https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html instead of wizard

Comment: What is the size of the input file in bytes?   What is result of SELECT @@max_allowed_packet; from your system?